# Restcomm mediaserver: audio file cache

Tags: restcomm, mobicents

I know that restcomm has disk cache for audio files.

Seems it provides **HTTP link** to mediserver to play file.

So each time mediaserver downloads file by HTTP and plays it.

Does it make sense to move cache to mediaserver?

Maybe we can use **"file://"** instead of **"http://"**. In this case mediaserver will read file directly from filesystem. Also mediaserver can has some ***memory cache***.

But if mediaserver is deployed to separate server it's not useful.
I suppose we can use distributed filesystem to solve this issue like NFS/s3 bucket.

What do you think?

Thanks,
Gennadiy

Comment: Gennadiy, we need to keep media server operations light and avoid as much as we can operations that can be done else were. 
Why you think it would better to move cache to media server?

Comment: @GeorgeVagenas, if set of media files is not big you can put them to memory cache and don't spend time to download them by http each time.